# Exceção de ponteiro nulo em um botão de rádio

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando colocar dois botões de rádio do PrimeFaces em uma página *xhtml*:

```xhtml
<p:selectOneRadio id="fis_jur" layout="custom" value="#{usuario.fis_jur}" required="true">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Física" itemValue="1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Jurídica" itemValue="2"/>
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="pessoa"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
<p:panelGrid columns="5">
    <p:outputLabel for="fis_jur" value="Pessoa"/>
    <p:radioButton id="fisico" for="fis_jur" itemIndex="0"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="Física"/>
    <p:radioButton id="juridico" for="fis_jur" itemIndex="1"/>
    <p:outputLabel value="Jurídica"/>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:outputLabel id="pessoa" value="#{usuario.pessoa()}"/>
```

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Usuario {
    public Usuario() {
        fis_jur = 1;
    }
    private int fis_jur;
    //getter-setter
    public String pessoa() {
        return fis_jur == 1 ? "Física" : "Jurídica";
    }
}
```

O problema é quando eu tento acessar a página, uma NullPointerException é lançada e não especifica qual a linha (da página), mas quando comento esse bloco da página *xhtml*, ela não acusa erros, logo, receio que o problema seja nessa parte, mas não consigo enxergar onde.

**StackTrace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(RadioButtonRenderer.java:51)
    at org.primefaces.component.radiobutton.RadioButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(RadioButtonRenderer.java:41)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:89)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:60)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeRow(PanelGridRenderer.java:142)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeStaticBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:108)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:81)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:68)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Já tentou debugar? colocou os Getters and Setters do fis_jur?

Comment: Como poderia debugá-lo? Eu só gero o war e faço upload para o Tomcat. Sim, os getters-setters estão lá.

Comment: Não entendi porque você tem o `p:radioButton` e o `p:outputLabel` com o mesmo atributo `for` apontando para o `p:selectOneRadio`. Pra mim o `p:outputLabel` deveria ter o atributo `for` apontando para o `id` do `p:radioButton`, e remover o atributo `for` do `p:radioButton`. Mais info: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml

Comment: @Wakim, fiz dessa maneira por causa do atributo "required" que coloca um asterísco na *label* que tem o *for* apontado para ela.

Comment: Mas não dá pra adicionar o `required="true"` também no `radioButton`? Você colocando o `for` do `outputPanel` para o `fis_jur`, linkou o dois, o `p:outputPanel` não está relacionado com o `radioButton`.

Comment: @Wakim, fica mais ou menos assim: Pessoa *  ( ) Física  ( ) Jurídica.

Comment: @Wakim, sim, é possível porém creio que isso não seria muito viável, pois é um *label* para dois radios.

Comment: Ah, entendi o que você quer fazer... Pra saber a causa desse `NullPointer` só olhando o código fonte mesmo.

Comment: @Wakim, o código fonte está ali.

Comment: Quando eu disse código fonte, era o do Primefaces hehe. Sempre que ocorre esses problemas é bom recorrer ao código fonte da biblioteca.

Comment: Revelo que essa exceção não acontecia, porém não lembro o que mudei e não tenho um versionamento. Como está praticamente igual ao showcase do PrimeFaces, não consigo entender o motivo desse erro.

Comment: @Patrick creio que o seu usuário usa o mouse pra selecionar esses itens, então não precisa colocar `event="keyup"` que é para teclas.

Comment: @Luídne Tenho quase certeza de que o keyup considera os cliques do mouse também.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente eu utilizo a variavel do RadioButton como String, você esta usando int.
Outra coisa, inicialize no @PostConstruct

```
String fis_jur;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    fis_jur = "teste";
}
```

Veja também exemplos no site do  [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml)